# Javascript variable loses value when string is taken from parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've created the following function:

```
function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
return {
    outputSpeech: {
        type: 'PlainText',
        text: `${output}`,
    },
    card: {
        type: 'Simple',
        title: 'Bible Library',
        content: 'Bible Passage',
    },
    reprompt: {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: 'PlainText',
            text: repromptText,
        },
    },
    shouldEndSession,
    };
}
```

When I normally call my function, the response is expected, everything is functional. However, in the following code, I make a GET request and change a variable within the GET request and then use my callback function with the changed variable. When I do this and I test for the output parameter in buildSpeechletResponse call, output is empty.

```
function getPassage(callback) {
    var url = 'privateurl';
    var body = '';
    var finalPassage = '';
    https.get(url, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(body);
            finalPassage = JSON.stringify(response.passage);
            callback({}, buildSpeechletResponse('Session Ended', finalPassage, "", false));
            return response;
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    })
    callback({}, buildSpeechletResponse('Session Ended', finalPassage, finalPassage, false));
}
```

When I test to see what finalPassage is before it's passed as a parameter, I see that it is the expected string. It seems as if my string is being lost in the call to buildSpeechletResponse? I'm not sure why it all of a sudden becomes empty. When I make the exact same call with an already given string such as:

```
var finalPassage = '';
finalPassage = "rand";
callback({}, buildSpeechletResponse('Session Ended', finalPassage, "", false));
```

The output is correct and output equals "rand" in my buildSpeechletResponse function. It seems like because I'm passing a variable where I assign it a string from my GET request it is lost? I don't understand how or why that would be though.

I call getPassage in the following way:

```
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log(`onIntent requestId=${intentRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);

    const intent = intentRequest.intent;
    const intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

    // Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers
    if (intentName === 'getPassage') {
        getPassage(callback);
```

Anyone know of any solutions or what may be wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you calling `getPassage`? Also, why are you calling `callback` *twice*, shouldn't you only call it in the `end` event handler?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I usually only call it in the end but by the time I got there, I noticed that finalPassage didn't contain the value that I had stored in my call. I then proceeded to add the callback within the call to see if finalPassage would still lose its value, and it did.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added my call to getPassage in the post above. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Currently, `callback` will always be called *synchronously*, before the `https.get` has had a chance to send a request out, which is surely not what you want? (maybe you're only looking at the first call of the callback?) The second in the `.on('end'` looks more likely to contain what you want

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was it. I spent so much time overthinking this. Thank you so much! You were completely right.